# How to load UIWebView underneath Navigation bar until StatusBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, navigationbar, uistatusbar

Hi I have a `VC` with a `UIWebView` and a `NavigationBar`. When I set the Top Constraint of my `webview.Top` to `Superview` and the constant to 0, The web view does not load until the status bar and only load until the navigation bar. Why is it like that? See the following pic.

[image: Pic]

[image: Pic2]

Then if I set the webView.Top to SuperView constant to -60. I will get my ideal output. But I don't think that is the correct way. Can anyone please advice.

The ideal output:

[image: Pic3]

[image: Pic4]

Comment: i face same issue ...

Comment: when you load data it will display extra space after loading it will gone.right?

Comment: use activityindicator for loading it may  help.

Comment: can you provide the link your are using in web view?

Comment: https://github.com/hansheung/SFITNESS/tree/03225530030e4e5210612b5897bbfe1f7c8482d1

Comment: Yes sometimes it will go away, I can't figure out what is wrong

Comment: you provide the whole code, I asked for the WebPage link you are loading in your web view

Comment: Currently it is internal page running on LAN, haven't got the website yet.

Comment: in that case try to load some other page(google any, and hardcore it for testing), and see if the problem remains. I think this might be issue on the web page.

Comment: Additionally do consider constraints with navigation bar, as mentioned in other comments and answers

Comment: The website is up, it is http://www.share-fitness.com/apps/loyalty.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I pushed the `webView` Top Constraint to -45 to SuperView. This will push the `webView` up.

I can't find any other answer.

Comment: -20 is also enough. no need for -45.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are setting the top constraint to Superview?Set the top constraint as 0 to navigation bar.It will work fine

Comment: But I want the web view load up to Status Bar, will that work?

Comment: @HansheungCheah I can't get you, if you want to show web view upto to the status bar then u can remove the navigation bar,if navigation bar there then you need to set top constraint to the navigation bar,if navigation bar have back button so you can get back to the home page.

Comment: @HansheungCheah hide navigation bar if you can't remove it, and add your own button for back navigation

Hide navigation: `navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true`

Back action: `navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)`

Answer (score 0):

Change the constraint with superview should work it has been attached with some view. however, you need to uncheck the Adjust scrollView Insets from storyboard

[image: Check Image.]

You need to handle special case for iOS 11